# How to recover the partition I accidentally deleted while installing new Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I had Ubuntu 20 LTS. I had two HDD partitions, one for my documents and the other for os and system files. I upgraded to Ubuntu 22 LTS. It had asked me if I want to format the drive before installing and I proceeded to continue thinking the documents drive/partition won't be affected. Now, the new Ubuntu has been installed, the drive/partition has gone and I only have one drive which seems the memory has been merged.

I tried testdisk but I don't have any luck with it. Can someone help me please? I really had important documents in that partition/drive and I can now only cry. :'(

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: "*I tried testdisk but I don't have any luck with it*". Try again -- that's your best hope. After that, you enter the realm of paid data recovery companies. You have learned a painful lesson on the value of backups. Sorry.

Comment: Hi @user535733, is the deeper search my best option? It loads up tons of stuff. I really cannot figure out which one is the deleted partition/drive.

Comment: As mentioned already, it is gone.  A deeper search by Google won't help you.  But backups and checking 2-3 times before clicking "OK" during partitioning is absolutely vital,  It is gone, unless you take your hard disk out and find a data recovery company.

Comment: By deeper search, I meant deeper search in testdisk.